# Verbe associé au mot « translation »

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques, demande-de-mot

Quel est le verbe à utiliser pour dire « faire une translation » ? J'ai pensé à « translater », « translationner », mais je doute que ce soit dans le dictionnaire…

Comment: Tout dépend de l'effet attendu. *Translater* bien que présent dans le dictionnaire et utilisé par les matheux et les informaticiens donnera un effet étrange en dehors de ce milieu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Le verbe **translater** existe bel et bien dans le dictionnaire.

Voici la [définition](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/translater).

Comment: Je suis surpris! Je trouvais le verbe trop facile que je n'ai pas daigné chercher dans le dictionnaire :P

Comment: Tu peux accepter la réponse si c'est ce que tu cherchais, merci !

Comment: StackExchange m'impose d'attendre quelques minutes avant d'accepter. Je vais maintenant poser la même question, mais avec "faire une rotation" ;)

Comment: Une autre source : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/translater qui donne les dates de début d'utilisation des deux sens acceptés.