# Verbe associé à l'expression « effectuer une rotation »

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques, demande-de-mot

Quel est le verbe à privilégier pour dire « effectuer une rotation » ? J'ai pensé à « rotater », « rotationner », mais effectivement, ces mots ne se retrouvent pas dans le dictionnaire

Comment: J'avoue que le « je doute que ce soit dans le dictionnaire » est un peu dérangeant : les StackExchange valorisent les questions dont l'auteur a fait quelques recherches. Vérifier l'existence de deux mots dans le dictionnaire n'est pas coûteux, ainsi que prouvé sur [la question sur la translation](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14577/verbe-associ%C3%A9-au-mot-translation). Je ne veux pas mettre -1 car tous les habitués des cercles mathématiques (dont moi) se sont déjà posé la question au moins une fois mais je bloque sur le +1 également en dépit de mon intérêt.

Comment: @Chop vous avez raison, j'ai modifié la question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Je proposerais « [**tourner**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tourner) » car une rotation, c'est étymologiquement le mouvement d'une roue et l'expression consacrée pour une roue en rotation est bien « la roue tourne » et par extension, on utilise aussi ce verbe pour tout objet qui effectue une rotation autour d'un autre, par exemple « la Terre tourne autour du Soleil ».

On trouve d'autre verbes ayant un lien avec le latin *rotare* (de *rota* roue) mais qui ne traduisent pas ou plus l'anglais *rotate*.

1. Le verbe [rouer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouer) correspond étymologiquement à l'anglais *rotate* mais son usage actuel essentiellement limité à l'expression *rouer de coups* ne laisse plus transparaître le sens original (tourner comme une roue). On le trouve dans les Essais de Montaigne (Livre II, Chapitre XIII):

> Songe combien il y a que tu foys mesme chose, manger, boire,  dormir, boire, dormir et  manger : nous **rouons** sans cesse en ce cercle.
> Il a un subsisté dans le vocabulaire de la marine, probablement jusqu'au XIX<sup>e</sup> comme synonyme de *lover* (un cordage).

2. Le verbe [rôder](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%B4der) partage aussi la même origine latine *rotare* mais son sens a lui-aussi beaucoup divergé et il ne peut pas être utilisé de manière générique.
3. Le verbe [rouler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rouler) est plus proche, mais suppose un contact avec un support.

*Rotater*, déjà évoqué dans la question, n'existe pas<sup>1</sup> mais on trouve les dérivés très proches [« rotateur » et « rotatrice »](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rotateur)

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>*Rotater* commence cependant à avoir une petite présence [« officielle »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rotater).</sub>

Comment: Je vais être honnête avec toi, je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un dire les mots rouer ni rôder dans ce contexte...

Comment: @milk2go Je suis bien d'accord avec ta remarque. C'est pour çà que j'ai indiqué que les sens actuels de ces deux verbes n'ont plus qu'un lien lointain avec leur ancêtre *rotare*.

Answer (score 11):

Je n'ai pas trouvé de verbe lié directement à rotation.

Le mot le plus proche est **pivoter**. Il y aurait aussi **tourner** qui pourrait être correct.

Voici la [définition](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pivoter/61247) de pivoter.

Comment: Pas mal, par contre, pivoter fait référence à une rotation sur un point fixe, sur un axe fixe (un pivot)

Comment: Dans ce cas utilise tourner. Cependant une rotation est aussi sur un axe fixe.

Comment: *Faire pivoter* est sans doute plus courant que *pivoter* construit directement.

Comment: @Goldorak84 ah ? parce que "faire une rotation" c'est pas autour d'un axe ? :)

Comment: Rotation : axe "appartenant à l'objet" : il tourne sur lui-même. Si l'axe est extérieur, on parle de révolution.

Je dirais que la rotation est le fait de pivoter autour d'un pivot.

Comment: @LeReferee : Alors est-ce que pivoter s'apparente davantage à une révolution qu'une rotation?  Selon ma compréhension(et l'usage qu'on semble en faire couramment), on parle de rotation si l'axe passe par son centre de masse (http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rotation) tandis que pivoter se rapporterait à un axe situé à l'extérieur de l'objet.

Answer (score 5):

Sauf erreur de ma part, il n'y a pas de verbe signifiant précisément "effectuer une rotation".

Pour s'en convaincre, il suffit de constater qu'aucun dictionnaire anglais-français ne propose de traduction intéressante pour le verbe anglais *rotate*.

A l'oral, par abus de langage, on utilise souvent *rotater* qui vient du verbe anglais *rotate*. Quant à *rotationner*, non seulement le mot n'existe pas mais en plus il est monstrueux.

Voici quelques mots qui, selon le contexte, pourraient être employés :
**tourner**, **retourner**, **pivoter**, **orienter**.

Comment: Du coup je ne pense pas que le verbe retourner est correct. Pareil pour orienter. Quelle est votre opinion? :)

Answer (score 2):

*[Rotation](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rotation)* vient du latin *[rotatio](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rotatio#la)*, nom formé suivant un modèle très répandu du participe passé *[rotatus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rotatus#la)* du verbe *[roto](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/roto#la)*, infinitif *rotare*. Suivant ce même modèle, le verbe correspondant en français pourrait être soit **roter*, soit une forme plus déformée s'il s'agissait d'un mot couramment utilisé en continu du bas latin au moyen français (dérivation populaire).

Ce verbe déformé existe. Le *[Dictionnaire du moyen français](http://zeus.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?ETYM=rotare;XMODE=STELLa;AFFICHAGE=3;FERMER;MENU=menu_dmf;ISIS=isis_dmf2020.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;ONGLET=dmf2020;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s003a0ec8;LANGUE=FR;FERMER)* cite même trois formes : *[raudir](http://zeus.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?LEM=RAUDIR;ISIS=isis_dmf2020.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;ONGLET=dmf2020;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s003a0ec8;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;)*, *[rôder](http://zeus.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?LEM=R%D4DER;ISIS=isis_dmf2020.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;ONGLET=dmf2020;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s003a0ec8;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;)* et *[rouer](http://zeus.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?LEM=R%D4DER;ISIS=isis_dmf2020.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=1;ONGLET=dmf2020;OO1=2;OO2=1;s=s003a0ec8;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;)*. Mais les deux premiers ont évolué vers des sens différents dès l'ancien français. Reste donc *rouer*, mais il se trouve que ce mot a été supplanté et n'existe en français moderne que dans quelques sens associés à une roue.

Dans le sens principal de *rotare*, c'est *[tourner](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tourner)* qui s'est imposé en français, alors que le verbe latin dont il dérive *[torno](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/torno#la) est spécifiquement associé au [tour de potier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tour_de_potier), venant du grec *[τόρνος](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CF%8C%CF%81%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82)* qui lui-même vient d'un mot qui veut dire « frotter ».

Dans les sens techniques de *rotation*, on aurait pu réintroduire une dérivation savante du verbe, qui aurait été **roter*. Mais *[roter](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/roter)* existait déjà comme dérivation populaire du latin *[ructo](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ructo#la)*. C'est probablement parce que ce mot désigne une fonction corporelle qu'on n'en a pas introduit un homonyme.

Du coup, il n'y a pas de forme verbale simple qui s'impose pour « faire une rotation ». On pourrait suivre le langage populaire et dire « [faire] tourner » (et les mathématiciens le font quelquefois), ou braver l'opprobre et dire « <sup>?</sup>roter » (ce que font certains étudiants), ou inventer d'autres constructions qui ne suivent pas des motifs habituels. « <sup>?</sup>Rotater » ne suivrait pas un motif habituel de formation : les verbes en -ater en français viennent en général de racines latines en -at-. Dans quelques cas (par exemple *[dater](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dater)*, [dilater](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/delater)*, *[relater](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/relater)), le -at- vient du suffixe latin du participe passé, mais il existait déjà un nom ou un adjectif dérivé quand le français a commencé à se distinguer du latin. « <sup>?</sup>**Rotationner** » suit un motif qui est productif en français moderne (*auditionner*, *collectionner*, *partitionner*, …). Ce serait un choix logique, mais il ne s'impose pas en pratique.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le cadre spécifique d'un mot de passe, on peut utiliser le terme **renouveler**

Comment: Cela ne répond pas vraiment à la question.

Comment: @Toto: Étant donné qu'aucun contexte n'est précisé dans la question cette réponse est a priori tout aussi valable.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Certes, mais renouveler n'a pas vraiment le sens de « effectuer une rotation » comme demandé dans la question.

Comment: @Toto: Ben si, c'est le sens 3 ici: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rotation

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Oui, rotation peut avoir le sens de renouvèlement mais pas l'inverse, renouvèlement n'a pas le sens de rotation.

Answer (score -1):

Un ventilateur qui réote avec un accent aigu sur le e ?

je réotus
il réotut
nous réotussons
vous réotussez
ils réotussent

Verbe : réotusser.

Bien sûr avec un accent aigu sur le e (ré.)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.